# AJAX call returning 'undefined'

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, undefined

AJAX call as follows:

```
$.get('file.php')
.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Console returns:

```
[{"0":"PS001","code":"PS001"}]
```

However if amend the log to `console.log(data.code)` it returns `undefined`. Also, traversing JSON using `each` as such:

```
.done(function, data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        console.log(value.code);
    });
)};
```

results in the following error:

```
[Error] TypeError: [{"0":"PS001","code":"PS001"}] is not a valid argument for
'in' (evaluating 'b-1 in a')
```

JSON looks well-formed, so not sure what the issue is?

Comment: `[{"0":"PS001","code":"PS001"}]` is that in **JSON ARRAY** or in **String**

Comment: @MokshShah It's encoded in PHP using `json_encode()`.

Comment: In case your `data` is a string, you will get the error. @Moksh is correct. [example](http://jsfiddle.net/shubh0602/v5j3gx1t/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON_ENCODE` returns string.

Learn more about [**JSON_ENCODE**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

You should convert that **JsonArrayString** to **JsonArray**

```
$.get('file.php')
.done(function(data) {
    var arrayObj = JSON.parse(data);
     $.each(arrayObj , function(key, value) {
            console.log(value.code);
        });
});
```

Comment: First to answer, and good pointer as I should have read the PHP documentation more thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, because your code return json array.

```
console.log(data[0].code);  //If you getting JSON format
```

OR

```
console.log(JSON.parse(data)[0].code);  //If you getting JSON as String
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vzno6kce/)**

Comment: This also returns `undefined`.

Comment: @Sadikhasan, OP getting string array instead of **array object**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.get('file.php')
.done(function(data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data)[0];
    console.log(json .code);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a `json` string. You need to parse it first. Try with -

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    console.log(value.code);
});
```